# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\sqrt{x^2 +4} - \sqrt{x^2 + 2})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So i have this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\sqrt{x^2 +4} - \sqrt{x^2 + 2})$$

Why can't I just divide by $\sqrt{x^2}$? Outside of the square roots you'd divide by $x$ (or $-x$). If I do this I'd get 1(1-1) which could be an answer right? The answer is $-\frac{3}{2}$ and I saw the solutions which make sense but I don't get why my method isn't right.

It has to be done without l'Hopital by the way!

EDIT sorry i wrote down the wrong answer from a different exercise

This is what I did:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\sqrt{x^2 +4} - \sqrt{x^2 + 2}) = \lim_{x\to\infty} 1(\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x^2}} - \sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x^2}})$$

And since $\frac{4}{x^2}$, $\frac{2}{x^2}$ are $0$, I thought the answer would be $1(1-1) = 0 $

Comment: Try conjugate roots.

Comment: @fcz: don't you mean conjugate *binomial* ?

Comment: The answer is *not* $-\frac 32$.

Comment: Please show more steps to your idea. By the sound of it, it doesn't make any sense. Why can't you divide by $\sqrt{x^2}$? Obviously, because that would change the thing you're trying to find the limit of. (I know this is probably not what you meant but answering me will help clarify your idea and what's wrong with it.)

Comment: You can take $\sqrt{x^2}$ outside, sure. $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sqrt{x^2}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 4{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac 2{x^2}}\right)=\\=\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac 4{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac 2{x^2}}\right)$$ Now what?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path You'd also divide $x$ to be 1 right? You divide $\sqrt{x^2}$ inside of the square root and divide $x$ outside of the root so wouldnt that be just 1?

Comment: @AnonymousRU Please clarify your question. Show the teps of your calculation so that we can show you the error.

Comment: You can't just divide, you can multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$. But yeah, that won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: I posted what I meant

Comment: I suppose it isn't fashionable anymore to expect 17-year-old people to use distributive property of multiplication backwards, so let's say that I multiplied and divided, and then I did three passages in one.

Comment: I clarified it now @SeanEberhard

Comment: You take the $\sqrt{x^2}$ outside, but that's not what I meant. I meant dividing by $\sqrt{x^2}$ (which is inside of the square roots) which would give dividing by $x$ outside of the square roots @SaucyO'Path

Comment: @AnonymousRU You can't do the limit of a different function just because it's easier to calculate.

Comment: What? I'm still taking the limit of the same function @SaucyO'Path

Comment: @AnonymousRU No, you aren't. $\sqrt{1+4x^{-2}}-\sqrt{1+2x^{-2}}$ is not the same as $x\left(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)$, and by a large.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have
$$\frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}=1$$
so
$$x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})\\=x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})\cdot \frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \\
=\frac {x((\sqrt{x^2+4})^2-(\sqrt{x^2+2})^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}\\
=\frac {2x} {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} $$
and therefore
$$\lim x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})= \lim \frac {2x} {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}$$
if $x$ tends to an arbitrary value.
We have
$$x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})\\
=x^3 (\sqrt{1+\frac 4 {x^2} }-\sqrt{1+\frac 2 {x^2}})$$
and therefore
$$\lim x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})\\
=\lim x^3 (\sqrt{1+\frac 4 {x^2} }-\sqrt{1+\frac 2 {x^2}})$$

but we  have
$$x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})
\ne 1 (\sqrt{1+\frac 4 {x^2} }-\sqrt{1+\frac 2 {x^2}})$$
except for $x=1$, so there is no reason to assume
that the limits of the RHS and LHS of this inequality are equal except if $x\to 1$

A different example is
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2}} x $$
here you have
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x \sqrt{1+\frac 4 {x^2} }-\sqrt{1+\frac 2 {x^2}}}   x\\
=\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{1+\frac 4 {x^2} }-\sqrt{1+\frac 2 {x^2}})\\
=\sqrt{1+\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac 4 {x^2}}  - \sqrt{1+\lim_{x\to \infty} 
 \frac 2 {x^2}} =0$$

But you also can use the conjugate trick from the first example:

$$\frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2}} x \\
=\frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2}} x \frac {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} {\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}} \\
=  \frac {(\sqrt{x^2+4})^2-(\sqrt{x^2+2})^2} {x (\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2})}\\
=\frac {2} {x (\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2})} \in [\frac 2 {x \cdot 2(x+1)},\frac 2 {x \cdot 2x}] {\to} [0,0] \quad ({x\to \infty})
$$

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply and divide by the conjugate:
$$
x(\sqrt{x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^2+2})= \dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{x^2+2}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1+4/x^2}+\sqrt{1+2/x^2}} \to 1 \quad (x \to +\infty)
$$

What you proposed, simply dividing by $\sqrt{x^2}$, leads to a different limit. You would also have to multiply by the same expression, leaving you more or less at the starting point.

Comment: Some thoughts on the downvote?

Comment: I think the owner means why he is wrong, not what the solution is.

Comment: I didnt downvote, how you did it was the answer but i dont get why my solution is wrong

Comment: @ClémentDato Point taken, but since he said that he saw the solution leading to $-\frac 32$ and it made sense, I felt the need to point in the right direction.

Comment: @AnonymousRU You did not post your solution... just mentioned dividing by $\sqrt{x^2}$. If you don't post exactly what you did, there's no way of telling for sure what you did wrong.

Comment: I posted it @PierreCarre

Comment: I don't see how it leads to a different limit @PierreCarre

Comment: @AnonymousRU If you just divide $\sqrt{x^2}$ you obtain an expression that is not equivalent to the initial one and therefore you cannot assume that the value of the limit is preserved. For instance, you **cannot** say that
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x} = \lim_{x\to ~\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x^2}} = 0$$